# Bijective function from $\mathbb Q^+$ to $\mathbb N$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$$\frac{m}{n} \mapsto  2^m \cdot3^n \in W,$$

where $W$ is the set of all $2^m \cdot 3^n$ for all coprime $n$ and $m$.
And it's easy to show there's a bijection from $W$ to $\mathbb N$.

Is this correct?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Which positive rational number is mapped to $5$?

Comment: It's a bijection from Q+ to W and then from W to N. Thus, 5 is mapped to a member of W.

Comment: If you're only to show that there is a bijection it's enough to use Schröder-Bernstein theorem. It says that since $\mathbb Q$ is countable-infinite there is a bijection. To give a concrete example on the other hand is a bit more demanding.

Comment: It seems like saying that there is a bijection $W \to \mathbb N$ sort of dodges the question, as the intent was to construct a bijection from $\mathbb Q ^+ \to \mathbb N$, was it not?

Comment: @skyking Why did you delete your example with $144$ ? It well shows the issue and that the map actually isn't surjective.

Comment: @Peter Because $144\notin W$. $W$ does only contain those $3^m2^n$ with coprime $m$ and $n$.

Comment: @skyking OK, didn't consider this

Comment: The $W$ argument works, but to nail it down I think you need the prime factorization theorem.

Comment: I have no idea why so many downvotes on this question! I learned something. +1

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show that there exists such a bijection then it's somewhat correct - because it only wraps it up by saying that there exists a bijection from $W$ to $\mathbb N$. If you want to give a concrete example it will not do because you don't give a concrete example of mapping from $W$ to $\mathbb N$.

However there's some handwavery here that I'm not sure that you're aware of. Besides you being sloppy about defining the mapping from $\mathbb Q^+$ to $W$ there is the motivation of the existence of a bijection from $W$ to $\mathbb N$.

The normal way one proves the existence is by Schröder-Berstein theorem. You simply proves that there is an injection from $\mathbb Q+$ to $\mathbb N$ (which you've done by example). The other way around is trivial since the identity map is injective. Now with injections both ways Schröder-Bernstein guarantees the existence of a bijection.

If you only want to show that $\mathbb Q$ is countable you only have to show that there is a surjection from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb Q$ or an injection from $\mathbb Q$ to $\mathbb N$ depending on what definition of countability you're using. For the second your construct will do, but then you don't need to go any further than the first map. If you use the first definition you can use basically the same approach, but reverses the definition.

Comment: My actual motivation was to find the easiest way to prove that \mathbb Q is countable. Does it do?

Comment: Here is the bijection from $W$ to $\mathbb N$. Map 1 to the smallest member of $W$, 2 to the second smallest member of $W$, and so on.

Comment: @Asmani 1 is not in $W$. You seem to be describing a map from $\mathbb N$ to $W$.

Comment: I stand corrected. Map the smallest member of $W$ to 1, the second smallest member of $W$ to 2, and so on.

Comment: Your mapping the smallest member of $W$ to $1$, etc.works.

Answer (score 1):

Your map makes no sense. Apparently, $\frac12$ is mapped to $2\times3^2$ and $\frac24$ is mapped to $2^2\times3^4$. Problem: $\frac12=\frac24$.

Comment: I believe there's no 2/4 in Q. It's a duplicate of 1/2, and duplicates are not allowed in sets.

Comment: @user475412 That's the most nonsensical comment that I've read here so far. Are you really saying that $\frac24\notin\mathbb Q$?

Comment: It's like saying is 2+3 a member of N? 2+3 equals 5, and it's 5 that belongs to N.

Comment: @Peter, sorry I didn't understand. Can you give a counterexample?

Comment: @Peter I asked this question to user475412, the person who wrote “I believe there's no 2/4 in Q”, not to you.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos The person who wrote this is Asmani

Comment: This is easily fixable by taking a suitable representative of each rational, having $n$ and $m$ coprime for example. So this objection is a bit superficial imo.

Comment: @Peter Since Asmani = user475412, I don't see the point of your remark.

Answer (score 0):

The OP started off by looking at $\frac{m}{n}$ with $m$ and $n$ being coprime, but then the logic went off-kilter. But the coprime idea can be made to work. Here we carefully describe a bijective correspondence between  $\mathbb N^+$ and $\mathbb Q^+$.

Set $F_{k} =$

$\qquad \qquad \{\frac{m}{k} \; | \; m \gt 0 \text{ and } m \text{, }  k \text{ coprime}  \} \text{ for } k \ge 1$

and note we can use the additional $a_{(i,j)}$  notation

$F_1 = \{1,2,3,\cdots \} \qquad \; \; \; = a_{(1,j)}$

$F_2 = \{1/2,3/2,5/2,\cdots \} = a_{(2,j)}$

$F_3 = \{1/3,2/3,4/3,\cdots \} = a_{(3,j)}$

$F_4 = \{1/4,3/4,5/4,\cdots \} = a_{(4,j)}$

etc.

where $a_{(i,j)}$ is the $j^{th}$ number in the $F_i$ list.

Example: The $2^{nd}$ number of $F_4$ is $\frac{3}{4}$, so $a_{(4,2)} = \frac{3}{4} $.

The point of all this is that each set $F_k$ is naturally endowed with a bijective well-ordering enumeration. Also, these sets are mutually disjoint and there union is precisely $\mathbb Q^+$. So we can now use Cantor's diagonal argument to set up the bijective correspondence between  $\mathbb N^+ \equiv \mathbb Q^+$:

$1 \; \; \mapsto a_{(1,1)} \text{ in } F_1$
$2 \; \; \mapsto a_{(2,1)} \text{ in } F_2$
$3 \; \; \mapsto a_{(1,2)} \text{ in } F_1$
$4 \; \; \mapsto a_{(3,1)} \text{ in } F_3$
$5 \; \; \mapsto a_{(2,2)} \text{ in } F_2$
$6 \; \; \mapsto a_{(1,3)} \text{ in } F_1$
$7 \; \; \mapsto a_{(4,1)} \text{ in } F_4$
$8 \; \; \mapsto a_{(3,2)} \text{ in } F_3$
$9 \; \; \mapsto a_{(2,3)} \text{ in } F_2$
$10 \, \mapsto a_{(1,4)} \text{ in } F_1$
... etc.

---

In a comment the OP states

> My actual motivation was to find the easiest way to prove that
>   $\mathbb Q$ is countable.

The above might be considered easy in that it does not require a terrible amount of mathematical sophistication. But sometimes 'easy' means 'lazy' mathematical elegance. Let us wrap this up with such an argument.

Any subset of a countable set is a countable set.

The image of a countable set under any function is a countable set.

The quotient set defined by an equivalence relation on a countable set is countable set.

The Cartesian product of two countable sets is a countable set.

$\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ is a countable set.

The subset $R = \{(p,q) \; | \; q \ne 0 \}$ of $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ is a countable set.

Define an equivalence relation on $R$ creating the [rational_numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_number). By the above 'easy' theory, $\mathbb Q$ is a countable set
.

Comment: I'm not very smart. What's the pattern in your solution?

Comment: As I take care of integer $n$, I make sure all fractions with a $n$ bound on denominator are taken care of. As you go out on the 'ruler', you get around to marking all 'tick' marks. Of course you have to know about 'simplest form' for a fraction. coprime stuff